# Method to test a deploy in production?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've to implement many changes in the production database, from create new tables to alter some procedures and constraints. The implementation in production is made manually by a third-vendor. I've to send them a file for every script. I'm fear that the implement make some error or anything happens. But as I've to deploy in stage the same script that in production, I've to make a good post-verification script before deploy in other environment.

So, I've the idea of leave a comment in every table, view and procedures, in order to test them, but I'm not very sure to use this method.

There is a better method to test if the changes were applied successfully without make insert/update/delete from the tables or not running the procedures, and get a "line" from the console in order the guy who deploys copy and paste me the output messages?

Something like... if the procedures wasn't created or the user doesn't have access, PRINT "ERROR ON THIS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I would read Andy's blog on "database test driven development".
   http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2012/08/07/revisiting-test-driven-database-development.aspx

2.
I would write every script in an idempotent manner.
In computing, an idempotent operation is one that has no additional effect if it is called more than once with the same input parameters.

3.
Either
A.  Have the third-party vendor send you the "text output" of the SSMS screen when they run the scripts
or
B.
Use sqlcmd.exe, and use the logging functionality, and ask them to send you the .log file.

-o output_file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Here is a .sql file that is "idempotent".  If the dbo.Employee.LastName column was originally 64 characters , this script would alter it.  Change to "NOT EXISTS" (and remove the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH check) to create any columns that previously did not exist (which is what 99% of my scripts look like on a db already "in service").
Also note the sqlcmd "placeholders" for variables.
But I could run the below script 1 time or 333 times, the result would be the same.

```
Use [$(DBNAME)]
GO

:Error $(ErrorOutputFileFromCommandLine) 

IF EXISTS (    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Employee' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'    )
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT * 
                FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] 
            WHERE   
                TABLE_NAME = 'Employee' 
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
                AND COLUMN_NAME = 'LastName'
                AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH < 128
        )
            BEGIN
                print 'Altering the column dbo.Employee.*LastName*'

                ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
                ALTER COLUMN [LastName] varchar(128) NOT NULL;

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                print 'The column dbo.Employee.*LastName* already exists and supports 128 characters.'
            END

    END

GO
```

Comment: Cool.  If you don't get a better response, and this helped you, "mark as correct answer" is appreciated.